# O que causa "Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in..."?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Fiz uma classe para conexão com o banco de dados usando PDO e na hora em que vou pegar os dados da minha tabela ele da esse erro.

Este é o codigo:

```
require_once('../class/connection.class.php');

$db = conection::getInstancia();
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM". conection::getTabela('TB_ARQUIVOS'));

foreach($query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $arquivo){
    echo $arquivo['Codigo'];
}
```

Ele da erro na linha do foreach

Comment: Esse erro acontece quando existe algum erro no sql, o que notei foi que o `from` esta colado com o nome da tabela. Tente imprimir a consulta e teste direto no banco.

Comment: usei a função 'var_dump' para descobrir o erro, tinha esquecido de colocar uma informação, no objeto PDO.

Comment: Você pode acrescentar a solução com mais detalhes em forma de resposta, no campo de respostas mais abaixo? Assim o conteúdo pode ajudar futuros visitantes do site. Obrigado!

Comment: O erro pode ser uma sintaxe errada no sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usei a função **var_dump()** na variável **$query**.

Inicialmente ela me retornava *false*. Daí fui verificar a linha onde instancio o objeto **PDO**, eu vi que tinha esquecido o **=** na parte do *host*

Antes

```
self::$instancia = new \PDO(self::$tipo_bd.':host'.self::$host.';dbname='.self::$nome_bd, self::$usuario, self::$senha);
```

Depois

```
self::$instancia = new \PDO(self::$tipo_bd.':host='.self::$host.';dbname='.self::$nome_bd, self::$usuario, self::$senha);
```